# Xml Documenting EF Code First Tables

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I know that I can document my tables using syntax like the following:

```
/// <summary>
/// Insert table description here.
/// </summary>
public class SomeTable
{
    public int someNumber { get; set; }
    public string someString { get; set; }
}
```

Which will show the appropriate summary when I use the table like so: `IQueryable<SomeTable> query;` However, if I was to use the table in LINQ:

```
var query = from p in db.SomeTable
            select p;
```

I would not get any intellisense description for the table. Obviously the solution would be to document the line `public DbSet<SomeTable> SomeTable { get; set; }` in my DbContext with the same description but that doesn't seem very maintainable in the long term. Is there a way that I can get what I want without having to repeat myself for every single table?

Comment: This isn't a criticism of your question, but there is something to be said for "self documenting code". `var allInvoices = from invoice in db.Invoices select invoice`. Do you really need Intellisense to know about what's in `db.Invoices`? Invoices, right?

Comment: @ta.speot.is I couldn't possibly agree more. Unfortunately I can't exactly go back and rename all existing tables (I have the access to do so but could potentially break a bunch of apps that I do not have the ability to fix).

Comment: Just get some refactoring tool like ReSharper and change `public class BadName` en masse to `public class Invoices`, whack a `Table("BadName")` attribute on that puppy and call it a day.

Answer (score 0):

XML documentation doesn't do much for IntelliSense (if you are talking about code completion only - I know that if you document your methods/properties, you get an additional popup with that information).

But order really matters. For example, if you said:

```
var invoices = from inv in db.Invoices
               join cust in db.Customers on inv.CustomerId equals cust.CustomerId
               where cust.CustomerId == myCustId
               select inv;
```

then you would get IntelliSense throughout. But if you reversed the conditions on the join (cust.CustomerId equals inv.CustomerId) then you would not get any IntelliSense for that condition.

EDIT:
Just noticed that OP is interested mostly in an IntelliSense **description**. There is no automated way to have that because you are basically wanting to see the description of your class on another class's property.

The property and the class should have separate descriptions. What if the property does more than just return the table?

Comment: In the currently implementation if I document my DbSet in the DbContext I get the appropriate summary of that table regardless of order. All I'm looking for is a way where I don't have to document it in two places since in order to get the description in both the LINQ statement and while using the class I have to document both the DbSet in the DbContext and the POCO class itself.

Comment: I updated the answer based on your comment. Normally, the comment on a property is a simple `"Gets/sets the invoice table."` I don't think there is going to be an easy way for you to see what you want unless you hover over the class's type name. That means you have to go to the context class and hover over your property's generic, or  maybe save your tables into variables, like this: `Invoice tblInvoices = db.Invoices;` Then you can use `tblInvoices` in your query instead of the properties, and you'll have the type name in close proximity to hover over.